# How to know all available fields/features in a database to build an efficient MongoDB query of a large (imported) database?

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql, mongodb-query

I am new to MongoDB, please bear with me as I have a question about the fundamental idea behind NoSQL and/or document-based databases. My question is how to query a database with MongoDB, efficiently.

Say I imported a database in JSON (or BSON) format. I know that MongoDB is a document-based database, and above all is a schema-less database.

My question is: how may I query a database if I don't know what's included? That is the available fields (features/keys) in the database. The database could be very huge and not every document may contain the same fields/features/keys (of course.) Even if I try to show some documents of the database, other documents may contain more or less of the fields I have already browsed/showed.

In an SQL database, I can show tables, take note of the fields (columns) and I will be sure all rows will contain these fields? I know some of the fields can be left completely, meaning they have no value, but still what other fields are there?
From my point of view, this means on needs to impose some sort of schema on my documents (the easy solution) but what about the imported data?

To rephrase my question: How do I know all available fields in an (imported) database, especially if it is huge, so I have a clearer idea about the data, and how to query it efficiently?